# Pulling git repository from local to remote

Tags: git, hpc

I currently have been working on a branch of a bitbucket repository locally on my computer, I need to update the same branch on a remote HPC system, I thought it was a simple as committing and pushing locally and then pulling on the HPC system but it still not in sync. The changes do appear when I am on the bitbucket repository but are not being updated on the remote system.

I was wondering how to approach this properly:

```
git branch

  development
* bugfix/xyz
```

I first push on my local system:

```
git push
Everything up-to-date
```

then I ran the following git steps on my command line when I'm on my remote server:

```
git checkout -b bugfix/xyz
git pull
```

get the following:

```
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> bugfix/xyz
```

but running **git remote show origin** on the HPC it says the following:

```
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: git@bitbucket.org:server/pipeline.git
  Push  URL: git@bitbucket.org:server/pipeline.git
  HEAD branch (remote HEAD is ambiguous, may be one of the following):
    development
  Remote branches:
    bugfix/xyz           tracked
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do
`git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/bugfix/xyz bugfix/xyz`

to fix your issue.

Personally I never user `git pull`, I really prefer `git fetch` to get what has changed on the remote. And then checkout and track a remote branch

Comment: I had an initial error but it got it working. Note though, it wasn't working properly with git fetch but when I ran git pull, it got everything in sync...

Comment: git fetch is not changing the current state, this is just downloading the objects and the refs from the origin. This allows to have a fresh state of your origin.